# Confused about "iterators" in python

Tags: python

I am studying python with the book [Beginning Python: From Novice to Professional](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599829), and I get confused about the section discussing `iterators`. There is an example in this section:

```
>>> Class Fibs:
...    def __init__(self):
...        self.a = 0
...        self.b = 1
...    def __next__(self):
...        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b
...        return self.a
...    def __iter__(self):
...        return self
...
>>> fibs = Fibs()
>>> for f in fibs:
...     if f > 1000:
...         print(f)
...         break
...
1597
```

To be honest, I only know that `fibs` is an object with methods `__next__` and `__iter__`, but have no idea about what happens in each step of the loop. And I made a test:

```
>>> isinstance(f, Fibs)
False
>>> f is fibs
False
>>> isinstance(f, int)
True
>>> fibs.a
1597
```

This makes me much more confused! Why the boolean value of `f is fibs` is `False`? And why `fibs.a` become 1597 after the execution of the loop?(Is the method `__next__` automatically called in the loop?) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well obviously it is called, otherwise `print(f)` wouldn't give you `1597`. And you couldn't do `f > 1000` if `f` wasn't an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 1  fibs = Fibs()
 2  for f in fibs:
 3      if f > 1000:
 4          print(f)
 5          break
```

Line 1 creates a Fibs() object, calling `__init__()`. Line 2 calls `__iter__()`, which returns an iterator object (in this case, just fibs itself). The interpreter will then begin calling the `__next__()` method repeatedly; it returns `self.a`, a plain number, which is assigned to the loop variable `f` (so of course it's not a Fibs() object and certainly not the one named fibs). When that value reaches 1000, the if clause will fire, print the result, and break out of the loop.

Comment: `.__iter__()` does not create a generator object. It simply returns `self`; and because `self` has a `__next__` method, it is an iterator. Generators are specialized iterators, but iterators are not necessarily generators.

Comment: If `.__iter__()` was a method that uses a `yield` expression, **then** a generator would be returned.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Get a little bit clear now but still have a question: is the method `__iter__` called only at the beginning of the loop? For example, I have tried to create a list `x=[1,2,3]` and `dir(x)` shows no `__next__` method but there is `__iter__`. So at the beginning of `for i in x`, `x.__iter__()` is called, returning a iterator that is really being "used" by the `for` loop. Is my comprehension correct?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for your help. I am clear now.

Answer (score 1):

> And why fibs.a become 1597 after the execution of the loop?

Well this is because it is going through the [Fibonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) and this is the first number over 1000 in the sequence.

> 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987,
>   **1597**, 2584 ...

Answer (score 0):

On enter to the loop interpreter calls `__iter__` method. On every loop step interpreter calls `__next__` method of `Fibs`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the loop automatically calls `__next__`.

The `for` loop does this to the given object:

```
# turn the object into an iterator
iterator = iter(given_object)
while True:
    try:
        # try to get the next value
        next_value = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration
        # for loop is done, run the `else:` block if there is any
        run_for_else_suite()
        break
    else:
        # set the loop target to `next_value`
        assign_next_value(next_value)
        continue = run_loop_body()
        if not continue:
            break
```

The [`iter()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) calls `given_object.__iter__()`, and the [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) calls `given_object.__next__()`; these functions offer some extra functionality and are the proper way of calling into the iterator API.

So, in each loop iteration, `f` is assigned the value that the `Fib.__next__` method returned.

You can also see that `Fib` is its own iterator; `__iter__` returns `self`. Other types can return a dedicated iterator object; lists do, for example:

```
>>> iter([])
<listiterator object at 0x129516610>
```

Returning dedicated iterators lets you create multiple 'views' on an object where each iterator maintains its own position, like nested loops:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
for i in lst:
    for j in lst;
        print (i, j)  # prints (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), etc.
```

or you can explicitly reuse the iterator:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
lst_iter = iter(lst)
for i in lst_iter:
    for j in lst_iter:
        print (i, j)  # prints (0, 1), (0, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in fibs
```

implicitly calls `fibs.__iter__` and binds `f` to all the objects that it yields, in turn. None of these objects are instances of `Fibs`, let alone equal to `fibs`. The whole is (roughly) equivalent to

```
# boilerplate, implicit in the "for" notation
__iterator = iter(fibs)
while True:
    try:
        f = next(__iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        break

    # your code, with f now bound to what the iterator yielded
    if f > 1000:
        print(f)
        break
```

(`iter` and `next` are the clean ways to call `__iter__` and `__next__`, respectively.)